# Custom Tab Bar Doesn't Show in Header View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, tabview

I have created a custom header but it doesn't seem to show within my header view. It works perfectly within its own simulator and with the page it's linked to. The header View is then called in my Home View. I do feel like I have over complicated my tab bar so any advice on this too would be amazing

Swift Ui ---- TabView

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabBar: View {
    @State var currentTab: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            TabView(selection: self.$currentTab) {
                homeView().tag(0)
                platformsView().tag(1)
                ebayView().tag(2)
            }
            
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            TabBarView(currentTab: self.$currentTab)
        }
    }
}

struct TabBarView: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Int
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    var tabBarOptions: [String] = ["Home", "Calculators", "Saved Items"]
    var body: some View {
            HStack {
                ForEach(Array(zip(self.tabBarOptions.indices,
                                  self.tabBarOptions)),
                        id: \.0,
                        content: {
                    index, name in
                    TabBarItem(currentTab: self.$currentTab,
                               namespace: namespace.self,
                               tabBarItemName: name,
                               tab: index)
                    
                })
            }
            .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.25) - 1)
            .background(Color.white)
            .frame(height: 80)
        
            Spacer()
    }
}

struct TabBarItem: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Int
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var tabBarItemName: String
    var tab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            self.currentTab = tab
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(tabBarItemName)
                if currentTab == tab {
                    Color.black
                        .frame(height: 2)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "underline",
                                               in: namespace,
                                               properties: .frame)
                } else {
                    Color.clear.frame(height: 2)
                }
            }
            .animation(.spring(), value: self.currentTab)
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TabBar()
    }
}
```

Swift Ui ---- Header View

```
struct headerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Image("logo") // <-- for testing
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.6)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Swift UI ---- HomeView

```
struct homeView : View{
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            
        headerView()
            
        VStack{
            
            Text("Calculators")
                .padding(25)
            
            VStack{
                
                Text("")
                    .padding(100)
                }
            }
        .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.25) - 1,
               height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.25 ) - 1)
        .background(.gray)
        .cornerRadius(25)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer : start all structs with uppercase letter.

Comment: TabBar : ZStack ?

Comment: With ZStack you TabBarView is over the selected view, so your header view is below it , so not visible. Use a VStack.

Comment: This has moved the tab bar to the bottom of the screen. I want the tab bar along the top. So header(), with logo + tabs at the top and content below

Comment: whats the reason for starting structs with upper out of curiosity

Comment: May be you need to do differently : VStack with header logo tab bar then the tab view.:

Comment: About the uppercase it’s a convention that is recommended . All codes may be easier to maintain this way as you directly make the difference between types and var. w more info [there](https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/)

Comment: tab view shoots errors when in the header, I've tried swapping it to header logo passing into the tabView and almost worked but still looks off

Comment: I did not meant tab vie in header view but below hedger view . All in VStack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244880/discussion-between-flamee-and-ptit-xav).

Comment: Sorry was not ready for a chat. I put what I was tiling about in answer

Comment: no i replied, i was trying to keep the thread cleaner but I have tried that and not sure im doing it right

Comment: Ready for the chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I meant :

```
struct TabBar: View {
    @State var currentTab: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack { // Instead of ZStack
            headerView() // moved here
            TabBarView(currentTab: self.$currentTab) // moved here
            TabView(selection: self.$currentTab) {
                homeView().tag(0)
                platformsView().tag(1)
                ebayView().tag(2)
            }
            
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            // TabBarView(currentTab: self.$currentTab) // moved upper
        }
    }
}

struct homeView : View{
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            
            // headerView() // Put it in TabBar
            
            VStack{
                
                Text("Calculators")
                    .padding(25)
                
                VStack{
                    
                    Text("")
                        .padding(100)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.25) - 1,
                   height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.25 ) - 1)
            .background(.gray)
            .cornerRadius(25)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i thought it was. it threw of the position of the logo which made me doubt my self but with some repositioning, it's all looking clean again

Comment: dont suppose you could have a look at my most recent questions?